# How to apply a radian to multiple resize drag handlers

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

You have a resize box with 8 handles, each consisting of a function to resizer its parent box size. Everything is bells and whistle, but upon applying CSS transform to rotate x degrees all hell breaks loose.

How would one apply a radian or such, so that each handler calculates the correct value while dragging a handler?

This is a [demo](https://codepen.io/jermaine-hercules/pen/KOMEdg) of the full working code with credit to its [author](https://codepen.io/niall-campbell84).

This is what one is trying to achieve
[Resizer handler illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYaVX.png)

---- Code Sample ----

```
/**
 * Drag Resize Bottom Right Corner
**/ 
drag_br: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x,
    y: self._startPos.y,
    w: self._startPos.w + ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    h: self._startPos.h + ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY )
  });

  self._repaint();
},

/**
 * Drag Resize Top Right Corner
**/ 
drag_tr: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x ,
    y: self._startPos.y + ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ),
    w: self._startPos.w + ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    h: self._startPos.h - ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY )
  });

  self._repaint();
},   

/**
 * Drag Resize Top Left Corner
**/ 
drag_tl: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x + ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    y: self._startPos.y + ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ),
    w: self._startPos.w - ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    h: self._startPos.h - ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY )
  });

  self._repaint();
},  

/**
 * Drag Resize Bottom Left Corner
**/ 
drag_bl: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x + ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    y: self._startPos.y,
    w: self._startPos.w - ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    h: self._startPos.h + ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY )
  });

  self._repaint();
}, 

/**
 * Drag Resize Top Edge
**/ 
drag_t: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x,
    y: self._startPos.y + ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ),
    w: self._startPos.w,
    h: self._startPos.h - ( 2 * ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ) )
  });

  self._repaint();
}, 

/**
 * Drag Resize Left Edge
**/ 
drag_l: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x + ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    y: self._startPos.y,
    w: self._startPos.w - ( 2 * ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ) ),
    h: self._startPos.h
  });

  self._repaint();
}, 

/**
 * Drag Resize Bottom Edge
**/ 
drag_b: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x,
    y: self._startPos.y - ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ),
    w: self._startPos.w,
    h: self._startPos.h + ( 2 * ( e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY ) )
  });

  self._repaint();
}, 

/**
 * Drag Resize Right Edge
**/ 
drag_r: function( e ) {
  var self = this;

  self.layoutRect( {
    x: self._startPos.x - ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ),
    y: self._startPos.y,
    w: self._startPos.w + ( 2 * ( e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX ) ),
    h: self._startPos.h
  });

  self._repaint();
},
```

I've already searched for a possible solution but each result with (use a plugin/jQuery) or an incomplete solution.

**What's the issue?**

Currently, the demo has a transform rotate(45deg) when click-dragging the wrong calculation is applied. If no transform rotate is applied it works as expected. This can be seemed by removing the *transform: rotate(45deg)* from the CSS panel.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? I don't want to fight against "all hell" without knowing my odds ;) Can you describe what happens that is unexpected? Where in the code is calculated / applied your "radian"? these kind of things..

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question to make my issue more clear.

Comment: Still I don't get the issue. For me it works a bit weird without rotate too: why would one want the box to stretch both sides, not the side that are being dragged? Anyway, if your issue is that a point you drag don't follow mouse cursor, thappens because your calculations don't take rotation in count. If i got it right, then the trouble is not related to JS. Take a paper and a pen, sit in your favorite chair and do the correct calculations \*shiahlabeouf.gif\* This comment is not very helpful, but if you draw the whole concept on a paper and then apply the rotation the solution will be obvious

Comment: Thanks for updating the codepen with the rotation (note that for the future, it's recommended that we have all the relevant informations right here on SO in case links rot). Your problem is that only horizontal and vertical coordinates changes are taken in account (places with `e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX` and similar). That's where you need to apply your angles, with basic trigonometry.. To give a hint, if you rotated your shape by 45°, the rectangle with should be changed by the projection of new mouse coordinates on a line at 45°

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, trouble is I completely forgot how to do trigonometry.

Comment: If I have time I'll show you an example with one of the corners handler, but it's worth remembering it, Pythagore's theorem and basic trigonometry are used everywhere in coding when graphics are involved

Comment: I've made no progress on this, thanks to my fantastic math ability wow, does anyone have a working example in the wild? Even something basic would be helpful.

Comment: currently writing a partial answer, it's actually more tricky than I thought at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, contrary to what I said in comment, the trigonometry is not that basic, mostly because it raises little coordinates problems. Forgive my drawing, hope it's clear:

- You want to know `X` which is what you ant to add to the width of your rectangle
- `B` is your angle (45°), which in JS and in radians gives `Math.PI / 4`
- You know `dX` and `dY` which are the coordinates of how much you dragged
- `A` is the angle of the dragging, `Z` is the distance

[image]

Now, these are the useful rules to know: Pythagore's theorem and basic trigonometry:

- Pythagore says because of the square triangle, you have `Z² = dX² + dY²`, so in JS:

`var Z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dX, 2) + Math.pow(dY, 2));`

- Trigonometry says that `cos(A) = dX / Z`, that gives in JS (`cosa` is the inverse of `cos`):

`var A = Math.acos(dX / Z);`

- For the same reason you have `cos(A + B) = X / Z`, it means that:

`var X = Z * cos(A + B);`

Last thing to know is that to get the height instead of width, you will use `sin` instead of `cos`..

**ADDITIONAL PROBLEMS:**

- The coordinate system is upside down for the Y axis: in trigonometry, when you go up, it's positive, on a screen, this is (usually) the contrary -> needs to negate `dY` to have the right angles
- When the vertical distance has been calculated with the right angles, you need to negate the result when going up (because you actually subtract height to the rectangle)
- In the picture the mouse could be below the horizontal line, in which case you need to subtract the angles instead of adding them (I recommend you draw it) and use `A - B` instead of `A + B`!!!
- I won't go into full details for this one, first thought would make one use `Math.abs(A-B)` to get the angle below the horizontal line, but actually you need to use `A-B` so that the angle is negative when the mouse angle is "inside" B (between horizontal line and your angle)

Now for the final code for the right bottom corner, hope you'll manage the rest (`X` in the example is `dW` here):

```
    drag_br: function( e ) {
      var self = this;

      var dX = e.clientX - self._startPos.clientX,
          dY = self._startPos.clientY - e.clientY, // same as -(e.clientY - self._startPos.clientY)
          Z = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dX, 2) + Math.pow(dY, 2)),
          B = Math.PI / 4,
          A, dW, dH;

      if(Z === 0){ //no division by zero please
        dW = 0;
        dH = 0;
      }else{
        A = Math.acos(dX / Z);
        if(dY >= 0){ //dragged up from horizontal line
          dW = Z * Math.cos(A + B);
          dH = -Z * Math.sin(A + B);
        }else{ //dragged down from horizontal line
          dW = Z * Math.cos(A - B);
          dH = Z * Math.sin(A - B);
        }
      }

      self.layoutRect( {
        x: self._startPos.x,
        y: self._startPos.y,
        w: self._startPos.w + dW,
        h: self._startPos.h + dH
      });

      self._repaint();
    },
```

Comment: Amazing my friend, you've given me a great head start with figuring out the rest.